# How to Save X Session -- ArchLinux+Openbox

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, x11, openbox

I use Arch Linux and Openbox. How can I save the state of my current openbox/X session and later restart them?

The scenario is like this: I've several browsers windows open, terminals, file managers, etc., and for some reason at any moment I may need to *restart* the computer. I would like to restore the set of windows I've previously using before the restart. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a session manager! Since you are running X one is installed by default! `man xsm`. If you do not like that one check out Arch packages. My computers usually have uptime couple of years so I do not know from the top of my head how to put the X session in the same state before shutdown or suspend. It should not be too difficult as  OS X does it by default.

Comment: `xorg-xsm` was deprecated on Arch some years ago now...

Comment: @jasonwryan Ok. I didn't know that you guys are using just peaces of X like FreeBSD.My Xenocara on OpenBSD include entire XOrg

Comment: @jasonwryan what alternatives do I have?

Comment: @JohnTortugo Run your WM in a session manager; XFCE has one (as does LXDE, Gnome and KDE)...

Comment: I use Openbox, I'll search for one that suits myself.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running the machine on a VM, You can suspend the guest OS and start it up again after the hardware reboots.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not.

Comment: I don't think of any other way. You can always reopen your windows from start up script. I think you may be able to find a flag to reopen last closed sessions for the web browser.

Comment: Chromium already do that. I in fact I use a plugin, called SessionBuddy, that do what I want, however for chromium windows.